# Using the data-* on input element

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

So i have discovered the data-* attribute and i have been using it with ajax to set the the id's on my link element destination.

Ex;

```
<a id="link_id" href="url_for_no_ajax" class="some_class" data-container="#main">Display Text</a>
```

So this way i can create a php function to make my link for non-java users and i use the id attribute and the data-container attribute for my ajax.

It is working fine.

I wanted to do the same with my inputs element but for some reason its not working. The data-* attribute is not showing in the source of the page.

So i must assume that i cant use the data-* attribute with input's

So my question is what element can take the data-* attribute?
or if it is faster to answer witch can't take it?

Tank you StackOverFlow Community! (=

**EDIT**

The line that output my input from php :

```
echo '<input id="'.$id.'" type="'.$type.'" name="'.$name.'" size="'.$size.'" class="'.$class.'" value="'.$value.'"><br><br>';
```

Then how i retrieve the value of this data attribute with Jquery for ajax :

```
var data_type = ($(this).attr("data-type"));
```

if i do `alert(data_type)` it is telling me its undefined.

Comment: `input` element does not appear at Question ?

Comment: Data elements work with inputs (and every other elements as far as I know), the problem must be with your code if you don't see them. Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Your element already has an ID, why assign it another one ?

Comment: The answer to your question, is that data attributs are common to **all** HTML element

Comment: No `data-*` attributes appear `echo`ed at `php` `echo '<input id="'.$id.'" type="'.$type.'" name="'.$name.'" size="'.$size.'" class="'.$class.'" value="'.$value.'"><br><br>';
` ?

Comment: There's no data attribute in that PHP

Comment: you must use `data-`before the attribute name in `data-*`attributes. That's why they are called `data-*`
 attributes

Comment: OMG yes just realyzed that as i posted it here i was actually doing it with the hidden field line instead of the visible one it is working lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inputs can take a data element.  Here is a test case:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/sL5tLhm8/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" data-container="a-tag">Click Me</a><br><br>
<input type="text" data-container="an_input" /><br><br>
<div data-container="a_div">Div here</div>
```

**js:**

```
$('*').click(function(){
    var d = $(this).data();
  alert(d.container);
  return false;
});
```

---

References:

http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

http://api.jquery.com/data/

> The .data() method allows us to attach data of any type *to DOM elements* in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

> So i must assume that i cant use the data-* attribute with input's

[`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attributes are global , and can be used at `input` element .

```js
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = document.querySelector("input").dataset.input;
document.body.appendChild(span);
```

```html
<input data-input="123" />
```